# Looking for MySQL/MariaDB where query over muliple rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, mariadb

```
Table Products
ad_id| property_id | property_value_id
69          4           1
69          7           6
69          6           3
67          7           6
...
```

For Example:

I need to search ((where property_id = 4 and property_value_id = 1) and (where property_id = 7 and property_value_id = 6))

Result should be: 69

The values im searching for are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad_id
FROM
    (SELECT ad_id
    FROM Producst
    WHERE (property_id = 4 AND property_value_id = 1)
      OR  (property_id = 7 AND property_value_id = 6)
      OR  (property_id = 6 AND property_value_id = 3)
    group by ad_id
    having count(ad_id) = 3) as subquery
```

Should do the job.

Comment: The result would be: 69,67 

I needs to be only: 69

Comment: @vivinox Try using the count() aggregate function in a subquery as in the code box i've just edited. Then you can select only distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table with itself three times, one for each pair of searched value. The query can take the form:

```
select distinct a.ad_id
from my_table a
join my_table b on b.ad_id = a.ad_id
join my_table c on c.ad_id = a.ad_id
where a.property_id = 4 and a.property_value_id = 1
   or b.property_id = 7 and b.property_value_id = 6
   or c.property_id = 6 and c.property_value_id = 3
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not possible, because its dynamic. Sometimes its just one pair of values, sometimes 10 or more pairs of values.

Comment: @vivinox If the searched pairs are dynamic you ave two typical options: 1) You can stored them in a temp table and then join them in this query, or 2) you can use Dynamic SQL to assemble a query in the for shown in this solution with dynamic predicates in the  `WHERE`clause.